# Javascript, how to retrieve ALL properties of a literal object in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, dontenum

i have a literal object like this

```
var O={

 toString:function(){
  // some code here
 },
 anotherMethod:function(){
  // some code here
 }

}
```

Im walk through object with for-in loop

```
for(var p in O){
 // some stuff with p and O[p]
}
```

The problem is toString property will not catch in the loop on IE browser!

Comment: for `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` objects you could use the .Keys() method

Answer (score 2):

Read this page: [ECMAScript DontEnum attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute) on Mozilla Developer Center. Basically, it's a JScript bug.

> JScript will skip over any property in
>   any object where there is a same-named
>   property in the object's prototype
>   chain that has the DontEnum attribute.
>   If a property with the DontEnum
>   attribute exists in the prototype
>   chain, or if the instance property is
>   marked DontEnum, it is not enumerated,
>   regardless of programmer defined
>   values for that property. JScript does
>   not properly check the DontEnum
>   attribute.